# C#: GPS Tracking system

Tags: c#, gps, system, tracking

How do I go about building a GPS tracking system with mobile (with GPS) in C#.net ?
The scenario is

1. Track a user (service engineer, nothing illegal here) via a GPS enabled mobile Phone. What software and hardware will I require? Is there any open source implementation?
2. For a vehicle tracking system, how do I go about with GPS? I would like to know the various steps/procedure. I am looking for some right direction.

Answer (score 6):

I built a Window Forms version to display information from a GPS.  Haven't really touched it much since, but if you are interested the code is on CodePlex.

http://gps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24953#146657

All that you need to do to get this tracking somebody is

1. Convert to Windows Mobile
2. Build a Web Service for recording location
3. Modify code to post location to Web Service every so often

Really I already did the hard work, or parsing the GPS commands from the serial connection for you.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Its actually not that hard (done it myself!).

Best place to start looking is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158708.aspx

You will need to download the windows mobile 6.0 SDK from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en

The sdk actually contains a sample GPS application that you can use to customize to your own needs.

Comment: Hi Calanus, wasn't that sample GPS application done in Visual C++ and not C#?  I haven't looked at the SDK in a while so I am generally curious if they finally released a C# version.

Comment: Nope the sample app was in c#. Have a peek at the following folder (once the SDK is installed). C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CS\GPS

Comment: There is a C# wrapper for the unmanaged API. Mostly good code but the WM5 version reported the position wrong (d'oh) and the WM6 version is still confused about local/UTC time.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this myself and I came across this

http://www.codeplex.com/SharpGPS

It's a GPS library based on .NET 2 full or CF, I haven't tried it yet but it looks pretty promising

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention C#, you will need a phone that runs Windows Mobile. And has GPS of course.

After you download and install the WinMob 6.1 SDK, you can simply start a Smart Device project in V. Studio.

You can read the GPS either through a SerialPort or use the GPS API. There is a managed wrapper for the API in the SDK samples folder. (The WM 5 version had some problems, Google for that).

When you can read the position, you will have to send it to a Server somewhere. WinMob has support for calling WebServices in a intermittently connected situations.

Comment: "WinMob has support for calling WebServices in a intermittently connected situations"  Could you please elaborate or provide a link to the documentation?  Thank you.

Comment: Guido, I have no idea what the current status is but it is called the "Patterns & Practices Disconnected Service Agent".

Answer (score 2):

you can find more info at:
http://www.miisoft.it/portale/index.php/programmazione/37-c/51-gps-parte-i
Here you can find notice about gps, parsing NMEA string and example code.

Comment: Link rot. Article is now here: http://www.miisoft.it/wp/gps-parte-i/

Answer (score 0):

1. First define the requirements, what functionalities your software should have
2. Decide on the platform: iPhone, Windows Mobile, Symbian, Android or something else

With "C#.net" you will likely be able to develop only for Windows Mobile.

Comment: Simply not true, at least any longer. Mono allows you to target iPhone/iPad, OSX, Android, Linux, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a vehicle tracking system, why not buy one, as there are plenty out there. If you don't really know how to go about it, I'm not sure you'll be able to produce a solution at lower cost than a commercial system.

Answer (score 0):

Try tracking location of GPS enabled mobile in PC:

1. develope android app in mobile (which gives permission to access GPS...coded in Android Manifest.xml)
2. develope PC app using .net which takes Location data from server and plot the location on PC by automatically generating Javascript