# C# Calculate n Number of Points along a Great Circle path between Two Latitude/Longitude points

Tags: c#, math, google-maps-api-3

I am plotting flight paths between Airports that I have Latitude and Longitude values for onto a Google Map (v3 of the API).

However unlike v2, v3 does not seem to have an option to put a Polyline on the map between two points and have it display as the great-circle flightpath.

So what I was thinking, was that it might be possible to calculate a number of points along a great-circle path between two Latitude/Longitude points.

I'm terrible with maths and I can hardly understand or comprehend how the great-circle calculations work.
Does anyone know of a C# library or code snippit that can take two latitude and longitude points and calculate a number of points along the great-circle path between them ?

Comment: were you able to get this done? I am looking to implement this in C# https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/142078. Will this work as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/924637/942855?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mike Gavaghan's C# Geodesy Library](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula/).

Comment: It looks promising however it seems to be able to calculate distances and bearings between points, but not calculate a number of points between two points.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the library doesn't provide for calculating points, too.

Comment: It doesn't, but you can just divide your A to B distance into a list of distances to iterate over and to pass each distance to .CalculateEndingGlobalCoordinates(reference, startPoint, startBearing, Meters, endBearing) . This will give you a lat/lng across the great circle route path.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a library included in the Windows Mobile 6 SDK

See a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062725/c-gps-tracking-system)

Alternatively look at this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2009/08/05/it-s-a-small-world-after-all-part-2-vb-c-and-gps-matt-gertz.aspx)

Comment: The Gavaghan library is amazingly high quality for free code. It uses high precision oblate spheroid modelling and supports all major geodata. Great Circle as used in the WinMob blog is a gross approximation.